# What is the practical purpose of contravariance and covariance in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, variance

I have just learnt what the terms "contravariant" and "covariant" mean. While there are quite some resources out there in the internet that explain what both terms mean, only a few briefly describe the purpose of both. So, I am having a hard time understanding when to use contravariant and covariant interfaces and delegates.  I also do not understand why some interfaces from the `System` dll are covariant and contravariant (which is what my question is mainly about), for example:

```
IEnumerable<object> str = new List<string>();
```

Why should it be possible to do *this*  instead of:

```
IEnumerable<object> objs = new List<object>():
```

And, if we assume that there is an `Obj` method that takes one argument of type `object`, why should an `Action<string> del1` delegate be able to reference that method?

Comment: Why create a `List<object>` just to pass it to a method that expects `IEnumerable<object>` and lose type safety? Besides, `object` is almost never used as a type parameter. A better example would be trying to pass a `List<Student>` to an `IEnumerable<Person>` parameter or variable. Clearly, when you have a `List<Student>` you *don't* want to get the data mixed up with `Employee` or `Teacher` instances

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I understand that exactly that is useful, I don't, however, understand the purpose of being able to create something like `IEnumerable<object> variable = new List<string>();`

Comment: You say you think it's not type safe - so please given an example of where you believe type safety is violated. What do you think you can do with an `IEnumerable<object>` that is unsafe to do with a `List<string>`?

Comment: You're using a contrived example. The code shouldn't have to mix up students, employees and teachers in a list just to pass it to a method that prints names for example. That's the purpose of being able to write `var students=new List<Student(); ...; IEnumerable<Person> variable=students;` or having `PrintNames(IEnumerable<Person>)` that can be called with `PrintNames(students)`

Comment: @JonSkeet I actually meant that writing `IEnumerable<object> str = new List<string>();` may be not type-safe. Well, that is not type safe because of the `object` and not because of variance then. My bad.

Comment: @Itsme1 that's your example's problem, not an issue with covariance. It's type-safe anyway. All types in C# are `object`s

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Exactly and I just realized that.

Comment: Okay, so is there still anything to answer here?

Comment: @JonSkeet I still don't quite understand why delegates require contravariance and covariance.

Comment: Delegates don't _required_ variance any more than interfaces do. But it _is_ useful, and for the same reason it's useful for interfaces. See duplicate for additional discussion.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I do not think that my question should have been closed for a comment that I have made. Also, that question that you said my question was a duplicate of merely says what a variant delegate is, not what its purpose is.

Comment: The second answer to the duplicate goes into great detail as to what the point of variance is. The fact is, Stack Overflow is not the correct forum for this sort of detailed analysis anyway. It is for answering practical _problems_ related to programming, not for educating people on the finer points of technical/engineering concepts.

Comment: @Itsme1: It's really unclear what your question *is* though at this point. Given that in response to my asking "Okay, so is there still anything to answer here?" you *only* talked about delegates, I don't think it's unreasonable for Peter to understand that's all that still confuses you. If the question were still open, I can't see how it could possibly be answered usefully. If you edit it so it's really clear what you're asking, it *might* be reopened.